# Call React.createElement with variable ReactClass name

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, so apologies if this is a stupid question, or if I'm missing something obvious, but I'm upgrading a project written for an earlier version of React to follow the new "createElement" syntax (we cannot use JSX, so all our code uses the native JS calls).

So, this:

```
React.DOM.div(etc);
```

Becomes this:

```
React.createElement('div', etc);
```

Anyway, to kick the entire program off, we've used a function outside of React-world which accepts a ReactClass name, and invoked React.render, like this:

```
React.render (window [ReactClassNameHere] (PropsGoHere), TargetGoesHere);
```

This worked just fine.

However, in React 0.13.3, that's no longer valid, and I can't figure out the right way to do it.  I've tried a variety of ways, including:

```
React.render(
          React.createElement(ReactClassNameHere, PropsGoHere, {}),
          TargetGoesHere
        );
```

...and:

```
React.render(React.createElement(window[ReactClassNameHere], PropsGoHere, {}),TargetGoesHere);
```

...and:

```
React.render(
          React.createElement(React.createFactory(ReactClassNameHere), PropsGoHere, {}),
          TargetGoesHere
        );
```

So obviously I don't know quite understand what's going on, nor how to fix it. Any help is appreciated, but please be gentle.

Comment: why is it not valid?

Comment: That's perfectly valid, see http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/mcb1kt38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one. Notice I removed {} from createElement. If you don't want child element, you should set that param as null or skip it.

```
React.render(
    React.createElement(ReactClassNameHere, PropsGoHere),
   TargetGoesHere
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did in fact work.  It turned out I was dealing with some combination of code gremlins and downstream issues I was mis-interpreting as a problem at this level.